# Apache Beam Python SDK with Pub/Sub source stuck at runtime

Tags: python, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

I am writing a program in Apache Beam using Python SDK to read from Pub/Sub the contents of a JSON file, and do some processing on the received string. This is the part in the program where I pull contents from Pub/Sub and do the processing:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as pipeline:
    lines = pipeline | beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadStringsFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.subscription)
    lines_decoded = lines | beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode("base64"))

    lines_split = lines_decoded | (beam.FlatMap(lambda x: x.split('\n')))

    def json_to_tuple(jsonStr):
        res = json.loads(jsonStr)
        ##printing retutn value
        print (res['id'], res['messageSize'])
        ##
        return (res['id'], res['messageSize'])

    tupled = lines_split | beam.Map(json_to_tuple)

    def printlines(line):
        print line

    result = tupled | beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
    result | beam.Map(printlines)
```

While running the program, the code gets stuck after the creation of PCollection `tupled` (no lines of code is executing after that). The strange thing is that when I change the source from Pub/Sub to a local file which contain the **exact same** content (using `ReadFromText()`), the program is working perfectly.
What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Pub/Sub I/O documentation (both the [Apache Beam docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.html) and [Dataflow Pub/Sub I/O docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io#reading-with-pubsubio)), by default, PubsubIO transforms work with unbounded PCollections.

PCollections can be either [bounded or unbounded](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/):

- *Bounded:* the data comes from a fixed source, like a file.
- *Unbounded:* the data comes from a source that is continuously updating, such as a Pub/Sub subscription.

Before you operate over an unbounded PCollection, you must use one of the following strategies:

- *Windowing:* unbounded PCollections cannot be directly used on a grouping transform (such as the `CombinePerKey` you are using), so you should first [set a non-global windowing function](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing#Setting).
- *Triggers:* you can [set up a trigger](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/triggers#setting-a-trigger) for an unbounded PCollection in such a way that it provides periodic updates on an unbounded dataset, even if the data in the subscription is still flowing.

This may explain the behavior you are seeing, i.e. the same pipeline working when it reads from a local file (which is a *bounded* data source) but not working when it reads from a Pub/Sub subscription (which is an *unbounded* data source).

Therefore, in order to work with a Pub/Sub subscription, you should apply a windowing or triggering strategy so that the data in the PCollections can be properly processed in the following transforms.

***EDIT:*** Also, as found out by @Arjun, it may be required to enable Streaming in the Pipeline with the option by setting the appropriate arg parameter using the following command:

```
pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the code working. But windowing alone didn't do the trick. Adding this line solved the issue `pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True`. Any idea what this does?

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.0.0/apache_beam.options.html#apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions), the `PipelineOptions` class is nothing but a wrapper to parse args. In this case, you are [setting the `streaming` option to true](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.0.0/_modules/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.html#StandardOptions), which enables Streaming Piplines, which you are using.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you found it useful so that the community sees this question as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I will. I'd suggest add the above point, i.e, to set streaming option to true, to your answer because the problem persists when it is not done so.